# Can we alight menu button center between left side of screen and La Rue image?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to align my menu to center but I can't position it.
This is my code:

```
    let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    space.width = 30

    let menuImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    menuImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu")
    let iconImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 65, height: 30))
    iconImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo")

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openCategory))
    menuImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    menuBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuImage)
    iconBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: iconImage)

    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - (menuImage.frame.width + iconImage.frame.width + 50), height: 30))
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search Bar"
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    searchBar.delegate = self

    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [menuBtn, space, iconBtn]
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item
```

[image: menu alignment]

Does anyone have ideas to help me?

Comment: Only time for a quick review but if you are manually setting space.width then the button should be created as `.fixedSpace` not `.flexibleSpace`

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, when I use .fixedSpace, it moves a little bit

Comment: If you are looking to adjust the spacing on the left then you are out of luck really as it's padding added at both ends of the toolbar by the system that you don't have access to.  The best you could do is try to match it with by altering the spacing on the right but the system could vary it.

Comment: Plus when you calculate the size of the search bar you take into account the menuBtn & iconBrn width and a fixed 50.  I would replace that with space.width otherwise in order to fit it in the system is adjusting the size of the space width itself.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, sorry Sir. Can you give me more detail because I am not sure about your ideas?

Comment: Do this instead of what you have `searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - (menuImage.frame.width + iconImage.frame.width + space.width), height: 30))`.  You can add some extra spacing if you want as well but you need to be taking account of space.width in there otherwise you chance it but the search bar size doesn't change and the space get adjusted by the system.